# Website not responding properly to a .aspx page and only downloads the .aspx file? What is going on here?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

So I'm trying to publish my .net application using `Visual Studio 2015`, and every time that i upload the files to the website, and then I enter the URL to my browser, it just automatically downloads the .**aspx** file instead of showing it like it should? What should I do?

I am "publishing" the application by simply zipping up the entire project and unzipping it to my public html. I have tried "publishing" using the FTP, and the result is the same when I zip and unzip on the website file manager in the control panel.

I have managed to run and execute it using `IIS` (Internet Information Server), and it works with no flaws! Though whenever I copy the files over to my web host's control panel (cPanel via TrentaHost), the website does not work.

This has been bugging me for about 3 weeks, if anyone has some knowledge please help me out!

Here is a link of what I am working on http://www.liverytrader.com/Default.aspx

Comment: Sounds like your web host doesn't have ASP.NET installed and is just treating .aspx files as static content. Contact them and ask them if they support ASP.NET.

Comment: I've already tried contacting them, they said that they don't help with coding related issues.

Comment: This isn't a code-related issue, it's a hosting issue.  @vcsjones is almost certainly correct here.

Answer (score 1):

You're using [cPanel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPanel):

> cPanel is a Linux based web hosting control panel that provides a
>   graphical interface and automation tools designed to simplify the
>   process of hosting a web site.

It means that you're hosting on Lynux, which doesn't support ASP.NET.

You need to find ASP.NET hosting to publish ASP.NET application.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to register asp.net with iis in the command prompt by running this command:

aspnet_regiis -i

Read about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: IIS is not my problem. I'm trying to upload it to a cPanel and NOT a remote computer.

Comment: After attempting to do what you told me, I get this :                                                                                                C:\Windows\system32>aspnet_regiis -i                                                        'aspnet_regiis' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.